# css motion blur effect for horizontal bar

Tags: html, css, web, photoshop

I have a little problem for converting a *photoshop* design to css :

**desired effect** : (done with *photosohp*, `drop shadow` + `motion blur effect`)
[image]

**current effect** (css) : 
[image]

css for current effect :

```
.horizontal_separator {
    height: 1px;
    display : block;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #100f0b;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding 0;
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #2c2626;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@karim  I've created a fiddle please check https://jsfiddle.net/3kn7vxk1/2/

```
.horizontal_separator {
  position: relative;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 0%, rgba(16, 15, 11, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 0%, rgba(16, 15, 11, 1) 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 0%, rgba(16, 15, 11, 1) 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#007db9e8', endColorstr='#100f0b', GradientType=1);
  margin: 1em 0;
   padding 0;
```

}

Comment: thx, but the problem is that the opacity effect is on the side not only left or right side

Comment: @karim I didnt understand. do you have any links?

Comment: i want the fade effect from both side, left and right, but with linear gradient the fading effect is only in the left side.

Comment: yeah that the effect i wanted, thanks you and sorry i'm news to front end dev.

Answer (score 1):

You could use css gradients to achieve this. heres a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpun5oao/)

With your css being:

```
.horizontal_separator {
    height: 3px;
    display : block;
    border: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666, #000, #666);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #666, #000, #666);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #666, #000, #666);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #666, #000, #666);
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding 0;
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #333;
    filter: blur(1px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}
```